How do I fix my closed form mathematical formula that returns 0 or 1 only whether or not theformula is true or false?
I need help with my mathematical formula in python. I want to fix it because it's returning -1 for some values and it's not properly returning 0 and 1 when n is the right number.
All I'm trying to do is create a mathematical formula I can use in python (only addition and subtraction) that can tell when the formula (n % 3) is 0. Based on the value of n it will return 0 if the answer isn't 0 or 1 if it's 0.
My code is:
n = 10
result = 1 - ((n % 3) + ((n % 3) - 1) + ((n % 3) - 2))

print(result)

The result should return 1 and 0 depending on if it's true or not so I can use this code properly.

n%3 can only take three different values: 0, 1 or 2. You can simply check each manually. If n%3=0 then you will print 1-(0-1-2) or 4. If n%3=1 then you will print 1-(1+0-1) or 1. If n%3=2 then you will print 1-(2+1+0) or -2. I can’t actually see how it would print -1. In general, your code prints 4-3*(n%3). Please clarify your question.

What exactly is allowed? Sounds like only n%3, constants and + and -, but then I think it's impossible.

The function you've described isn't linear, so achieving your goal with only addition and subtraction is impossible. You need to update the question with more details about the requirements.

The issue with your formula is that its overly complex and does not correctly implement the logic you want that is: returning 1ifn % 3 == 0 and 0 otherwise.
Simplest approach
if you are okay using conditional expressions in python, this is the easiest solution:
n = 10
result = 1 if n % 3 == 0 else 0
print(result)


Or, even more simply: int(not n % 3)

@s3dev Or +(not n % 3) or 1 >> n%3.

As far as only addition and subtraction cat be used, this is not an answer to the OP

Your question is a little unclear. If you are not allowed to use the modulus operator, then you might do something like this:
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                              

n = 20
m = 3

if n < 0: raise ValueError("Error: Positive n required")
if m < 1: raise ValueError("Error: Positive non-zero m required")

def test(n, m):
    i = 0
    if n == 0:
        return True
    while n != 0:
        if (i + 1) == m and n != 1:
            i = 0
            n -= 1
        elif (i + 1) == m and n < m:
            return (n - 1) == 0
        else:
            i += 1
            n -= 1
    return False

print(test(n, m))


You could use
result=(1,0,0)[n%3]

or
result=(n%3-1)*(n%3-2)//2

Perhaps the second one is using too many operators other than addition and subtraction - but then you were using the remainder (modulo) operator % anyway.

Building a list for each lookup is relatively expensive, better use a tuple so it's a constant.

Good point; switched from list to tuple.
